# No solutions exist for $2a^2 + 3b^2 = 6c^2$ for $a,b,c \in N$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> How to prove that
> No solutions exist for $2a^2 + 3b^2 = 6c^2$ for $a,b,c  \in N$

---

Attempt:

Since  $3∣3b^2$  and  $3∣6c^2$ , we must have  $3∣2a^2$   and thus  $3∣a$.
Since  $2∣2a^2$  and  $2∣6c^2$ , we must have  $2∣3a^2$   and thus  $2∣b$.

Let $a = 3A , b = 2B$

$18A^2 + 12B^2 = 6c^2$

$3A^2 + 2B^2 = c^2$

---

I am stuck here. Reducing this equation using modular arithmetic does not seem to help.